# How do I leave a trail behind my shapes in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Right now I have shapes that are created when the user spins the mouse wheel and they slowly fade away after a certain amount of time. How would I generate a trail behind each shape that follows it and also slowly disappears? Here's the code:

```js
    var canvas;
    var context;
    var triangles = [];
    var timer;

    function init() {
      canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      resizeCanvas();
      window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);
      canvas.onwheel = function(event) {
        handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      };
      var timer = setInterval(resizeCanvas, 30);
    }

    function Triangle(x, y, triangleColor) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.triangleColor = triangleColor;

      this.vx = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
      this.vy = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
      this.time = 100;
    }

    function handleClick(x, y) {
      var colors = [
        [0, 170, 255],
        [230, 180, 125],
        [50, 205, 130]
      ];
      var triangleColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
      triangles.push(new Triangle(x, y, triangleColor));
      for (var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
        drawTriangle(triangles[i]);
      }
    }

    function drawTriangle(triangle) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(triangle.x, triangle.y);
      context.lineTo(triangle.x + 25, triangle.y + 25);
      context.lineTo(triangle.x + 25, triangle.y - 25);
      var c = triangle.triangleColor
      context.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + c[0] + ', ' + c[1] + ', ' + c[2] + ', ' + (triangle.time / 100) + ')';
      context.fill();
    }

    function resizeCanvas() {
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
      fillBackgroundColor();
      for (var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
        var t = triangles[i];
        drawTriangle(t);

        if (t.x + t.vx > canvas.width || t.x + t.vx < 0)
          t.vx = -t.vx
        if (t.y + t.vy > canvas.height || t.y + t.vy < 0)
          t.vy = -t.vy
        if (t.time === 0) {
          triangles.splice(i, 1);
        }

        t.time -= 1;
        t.x += t.vx;
        t.y += t.vy;
      }
    }

    function fillBackgroundColor() {
      context.fillStyle = "black";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }


  init()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's Sunday. Here's a way of doing it that works:

1. Add an empty array and opacity property to triangle object properties in the constructor, calling them, say, `trails` and `alpha` respectively.
2. Define the maximum number of ghost triangles you want in the trail. I found 3 a good value:

   ```
       var MAX_GHOSTS = 3;
   ```
3. Make the triangle drawing function take an alpha channel value as its second parameter and remove opacity calculation from within the function itself:

   ```
       function drawTriangle(triangle, alpha) { // two parameters required }
   ```
4. Where triangles are currently drawn in the timer callback (within the loop), calculate and update the triangle's alpha value  used in the call to `drawTriangle`. Push a *copy* of selected triangle properties  onto the triangle's trails array: copying freezes the x,y position. Not pushing every timer call spaces the ghost images further apart:

   ```
       if( t.time%2 == 0) {
           t.trails.push(
            { x: t.x, y: t.y, alpha: t.alpha, triangleColor: t.triangleColor}
            );
       }
   ```
5. Also in the timer call back, before the existing drawing loop, add a new double nested loop structure where

   - the outer loop retrieves the trails array of each entry in the triangles array. If the trails array length is more than MAX_GHOST, remove its first element (using `splice`).
   - the inner loop, using say `j` as the index, gets the next elements from the trails array, calling it `crumb` for example. Calculate an alpha value to make it fade quickly and draw it:

     ```
          drawTriangle( crumb, (j+1)/(MAX_GHOSTS + 2) * crumb.alpha);
     ```

Hope you enjoy!